# Converting numbers to words - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that converts all numbers less than 100,000,000 into word form. The code below converts each digit except for the tens-millions number and I am not sure why. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!!

```
## 
#  This program turns an integer into its English name.
#

def main() :
   value = int(input("Please enter a positive integer < 1000000000: "))
   print(intName(value))

## Turns a number into its English name.
#  @param number a positive integer < 1,000,000,000
#  @return the name of the number (e.g. "two hundred seventy four")
#



def intName(number):
   part = number
   name = ""

   if part >= 100000000:
      name = thousands(part // 10000000) + " million"
      part = part % 1000000

   if part >= 1000:
      name = name + " " + thousands(part // 1000) + " thousand"
      part = part % 1000

   if part > 0:
      name = name + " " + thousands(part)
      part = 0

   if part > 0:
      name = name + " " + thousands(part)
      part = 0

   return name



def thousands(number) :
   part = number   # The part that still needs to be converted.
   name = ""   # The name of the number. 

   if part >= 100 :
      name = digitName(part // 100) + " hundred"
      part = part % 100

   if part >= 20 :
      name = name + " " + tensName(part)
      part = part % 10
   elif part >= 10 :
      name = name + " " + teenName(part)
      part = 0

   if part > 0 :
      name = name + " " + digitName(part)

   return name

## Turns a digit into its English name.
#  @param digit an integer between 1 and 9
#  @return the name of digit ("one" ... "nine")
#
def digitName(digit) :
   if digit == 1 : return "one"
   if digit == 2 : return "two"
   if digit == 3 : return "three"
   if digit == 4 : return "four"
   if digit == 5 : return "five"
   if digit == 6 : return "six"
   if digit == 7 : return "seven"
   if digit == 8 : return "eight"
   if digit == 9 : return "nine"
   return ""

## Turns a number between 10 and 19 into its English name.
#  @param number an integer between 10 and 19
#  @return the name of the given number ("ten" ... "nineteen")
#
def teenName(number) :
   if number == 10 : return "ten"
   if number == 11 : return "eleven"
   if number == 12 : return "twelve"
   if number == 13 : return "thirteen"
   if number == 14 : return "fourteen"
   if number == 15 : return "fifteen"
   if number == 16 : return "sixteen"
   if number == 17 : return "seventeen"
   if number == 18 : return "eighteen"
   if number == 19 : return "nineteen"
   return ""

## Gives the name of the tens part of a number between 20 and 99.
#  @param number an integer between 20 and 99
#  @return the name of the tens part of the number ("twenty" ... "ninety")
#
def tensName(number) :
   if number >= 90 : return "ninety"
   if number >= 80 : return "eighty"
   if number >= 70 : return "seventy"
   if number >= 60 : return "sixty"
   if number >= 50 : return "fifty"
   if number >= 40 : return "forty"
   if number >= 30 : return "thirty"
   if number >= 20 : return "twenty"
   return ""

# Start the program.
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your first if block which checks for millions has too many zeroes, you want to add millions if `part` is greater than one million (`1000000`) and instead you are checking against one hundred million (`100000000`).  Then in the first line of that if block you want to divide by one million and instead you are dividing by ten million.

Try changing that piece to the following:

```
   if part >= 1000000:
      name = thousands(part // 1000000) + " million"
      part = part % 1000000
```